# Getting String cannot be cast into Integer error

Tags: android, exception

I am getting this error, but don't know why. Here

```
feedArray.get(mJazzy.getCurrentItem()).get("TotalCount_Smasheys")
```

returns an Object type. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3661441/2944070) link to cast `Object` to `Integer`.

Screen 1: Here I inspected:

```
feedArray.get(mJazzy.getCurrentItem()).get("TotalCount_Smasheys")
```

and got value:

[image: screen 1]

Screen 2: Here I inspected: (Integer)(feedArray.get(mJazzy.getCurrentItem()).get("TotalCount_Smasheys")) and it throws exception:

[image: screen 2]

EDIT: It is very confusing. *feedArray.get(mJazzy.getCurrentItem()).get("TotalCount_Smasheys")* returns me an Object, which is actually an Integer, so I can't use (String) on it.

Answer (score 1):

first use String.trim() Then,
instead of casting to **Integer** Use **Integer.parseInt()** or **Integer.valueOf()**
It'll might help.

Comment: so, use **Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(<your variable>))** this will work on Object type

Answer (score 0):

That's because the string has spaces. Remove the spaces from the string first and then use Integer.parseInt() to change it to integer.

You can use `string.trim()` or `string.replace(" ","")` to remove whitespaces.

Comment: Check screen 1, it is an object with count 2 i.e. "3" and "1"

Comment: that's not "3" and "1". That's "31 ". That's a lot different.

Comment: No, it's because you can't cast a string to an integer.

Comment: That's why I've put Integer.parseInt() in my solution.

Comment: As I mentioned, feedArray.get(mJazzy.getCurrentItem()).get("TotalCount_Smasheys")  gives me Object not String.

Comment: What is feedArray? Is an array of what?

Comment: Array of ParseObjects.

Comment: Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mJazzy.getCurrentItem()).get("TotalCount_Smasheys"))) This works for you?

Answer (score 0):

It lloks like "31" is not an integer but a string. Did you try

```
int i = Integer.valueOf((String) your_object);
```

Answer (score 0):

The method

```
feedArray.get(mJazzy.getCurrentItem()).get("TotalCount_Smasheys")
```

is returning a `String`, not an `Integer`.

Convert it to integer using `Integer.parseInt()`:

```
String countString = (String) feedArray.get(mJazzy.getCurrentItem()).get("TotalCount_Smasheys");
Integer countInt = Integer.parseInt(countString);
```

Comment: It clearly is not an `Integer` otherwise it wouldn't crash that way. Did you try my answer? What error did you get using it?

Comment: Actually feedArray is an ArrayList of type ParseObject. And ParseObject.get("key") returns an "Object", not an Integer. But the value is actually an Integer, so the Object it returns automatically becomes Integer. Hope u understand what I said lol.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: Ok, you need to do what Eclipse is suggesting (and I also forgot to do, sorry for that): cast the string. I've updated my answer.

Comment: The problem is that the Object can be anything, String or Integer. If it returns Integer, then  it will cause error here.