# Java - get an Integer value from String or int - avoiding instanceof

Tags: java, casting, integer, instanceof

Is there a single line implementation for the `getInt` method?

If not - can one implement it without using `instanceof`?

```
public class ParseInt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object intArr[] = { "131", 232, new Integer(333) };

        for (Object intObj : intArr) {
            System.out.println(getInt(intObj));
        }
    }

    private static int getInt(Object obj) {
        return // ???
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you even mention reflection? There's no need for it. There *is* need for `instanceof`, though, but that's not reflection.

Comment: `return obj instanceof Number? ((Number)obj).intValue() : Integer.parseInt((String)obj);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to cast an Object to an int in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661413/how-to-cast-an-object-to-an-int-in-java)

Comment: OK, I meant `instanceof` not reflection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Integer.valueOf(obj.toString)`

```
private static int getInt(Object obj) {
    return Integer.valueOf(obj.toString());
}
```

This will work for your object array

Comment: This would die in the event that `obj` was `null`. You could use `String#valueOf(Object)` instead, which returns the String `"null"` if the passed argument is `null`.

Comment: @JonK - `String#valueOf(Object)` will throw `NumberFormatException` instead of `NPE`. Why is your suggestion better?

Comment: @Elist Really it's a matter of personal preference. It's for you to decide which exception is more meaningful for a given situation. If you would prefer a `NullPointerException` then go for that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like...

```
private static int getInt(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof String) {
        return Integer.parseInt((String) obj);
    } else if(obj instanceof Integer){
        return (Integer) obj;
    } else{
        return 0; // or else whatever you want
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also use `String#valueOf(Object)` instead of a cast

Comment: Let's just hope `obj` is not an instance of `XXX` (any class but `String` or `Integer`)