# Performing Integers operation on List<Objects>

Tags: java, list, object, type-conversion

I have a List of `Objects` which I want to convert to a List of `Integers`

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add("StringTest");
list.add(10);
list.add(5.9);
list.add(2.5f);
list.add(12L);
...            // different datatypes

List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
// convert items from list and add to result
```

What could be a good custom implementation to add values from different datatypes of `List<Object>` to a `List<Integer>`

1. Strings may be appended based on their length.
2. Floating numbers needs to be rounded

I know standard implmentation on [How to cast an Object to an int in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661413/how-to-cast-an-object-to-an-int-in-java) but I am looking for a good structure to write a generic one.

Comment: It sounds like you already have a plan for how to implement it. Are you stuck on something?

Comment: It seems like Java 8 has a sneaky way of using streams to handle type conversion. Initially, I was thinking of writing method that can handle different `instanceof` operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use streams to process the list of `Object` types as shown in the below code (follow the comments):

```
//Collect all Number types to ints
List<Integer> output1 = list.stream().
    filter(val -> !(val instanceof String)).//filter non-String types
    map(val -> ((Number)val).floatValue()).//convert to Number & get float value
    map(val -> (int)Math.round(val)).//apply Math.round
    collect(Collectors.toList());//collect as List

//Collect all String types to int
List<Integer> output2 = list.stream().
      filter(val -> (val instanceof String)).//filter String types
       map(val -> (((String)val).length())).//get String lengths
       collect(Collectors.toList());//collect as List

//Now, merge both the lists
output2.addAll(output1);
```

---

> Floating numbers needs to be rounded

You need to first convert the `Number` value to `float` using `floatValue()` method and then apply `Math.round` as shown above.

Comment: Looks awesome. However, could you please tell me if I can use `Math.round` on this to the nearest decimal value?

Comment: I have updated the code, have a look to use `Math.round`

Comment: Thanks @javaguy for the code and explanation (comments). `streams` are powerful and I should start using them.

Comment: yes, you are right, they are very powerful i.e., they provide clean/simpler code  to process the data

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add just numbers and don't process strings, than you can use this:

```
   List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add("StringTest");
    list.add(10);
    list.add(5.9);
    list.add(2.5f);
    list.add(12L);

    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

     list.stream().filter(element -> element instanceof Number)
            .map(Number.class::cast)
            .mapToDouble(Number::doubleValue)
            .mapToLong(Math::round)
            .mapToInt(Math::toIntExact) // can throw ArithmeticException if long value overflows an int
            .forEach(result::add);
```

If you also want to process string, than you need to replace string in list with int values of there length and then process as mentioned above.

Comment: Good one Arthur. That's why I was thinking of a custom implementation where I can `round` the floating point numbers to the `nearest value`.

Comment: Thank you for your code @Arthur. I wish I could accept multiple answers on SO.

Answer (score 1):

The `instanceof` operator would make this relatively simple.

```
public class Convert {
    public static int toInt(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof String) {
            return ((String)o).length();
        } else if (o instanceof Number) {
            return Math.round(((Number)o).floatValue());
        } else {
            return o.hashCode(); // or throw an exception
        }
    }
}
```

With Java 8, you could convert the values with a `Stream`.

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add("StringTest");
list.add(10);
list.add(5.9);
list.add(2.5f);
list.add(12L);

List<Integer> result = list.stream().map(Convert::toInt).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

With this you can add to the Integer list at the same time when you add to the object list

```
final List<Integer> integerList=new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Object> list=new ArrayList<Object>(){

  public boolean add(Object e) {
    if(e instanceof String){
      integerList.add(((String)e).length());
    }
    if (e instanceof Float){
      integerList.add(Math.round((float) e));
    }
    else{
      // other cases
    }
    return super.add(e);
  };
};
list.add("StringTest");
list.add(10);
list.add(5.9);
list.add(2.5f);
list.add(12L);
```