# ClassCastException when cast generic list to specific type

Tags: java

In the following code I got `ClassCastException` only on the 6th line when get actual value from `List` of strings as integer. But I want to get this exception earlier in 4th line. As you can see 5th line works correct without `ClassCastException`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> original = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
    Object obj = original;
    List<Integer> li = (List<Integer>)obj;
    System.out.println(li); //[1, 2, 3]
    Integer ei = li.get(0); //java.lang.ClassCastException
}
```

I understand that `List` contains only references to actual objects (values) and don't know anything about actual content before read. Is there any correct way to throw `ClassCastException` on the 4th line?

Comment: As far as I'm aware of there is no handy way to get the exception on line 4, but why would you need that? I would try to avoid `Object` altogether.

Comment: One lesson is to be taken from this: don't ignore the compiler warning (`Unchecked cast from Object to List<Integer>`)

Answer (score 1):

You have bypassed the compiler check for generic types by using `Object` and casts:

```
List<Integer> li = (List<Integer>) (Object) Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
Integer i = li.get(0);
```

You won't get a `ClassCastException` in line 4 since in runtime generic information is not present due to [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). The code is compiled more or less as:

```
List li = (List) Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3"); // all good, still List
Integer i = (Integer) li.get(0); // ClassCastException
```

Answer (score 1):

The only compile-time **warning** you can get is

```
java: unchecked cast
  required: java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>
  found:    java.lang.Object
```

Which can be obtained using the

```
-Xlint:unchecked
```

compilation parameter.
At runtime, it's not possible, as upcasting is always allowed to `Object`, and downcasting is always allowed from `Object` in this case (as you're targeting a `List`).

Answer (score 1):

As the compiler warning was trying to tell you (the warning on line 4): The generics bits in a type assertion (a cast where the thingie in the parentheses is a non-primitive type) are not checked at all, the compiler just trusts you.

it's literally a type assertion (you, the programmer, is informing the compiler that it should make a presumption about what's in there).

The only way to do something like this is to loop through each and every element in that list and check if it is an Integer.

Answer (score 0):

cast object to array of integer needs to be convert first string then Integer.

```
        List<String> original = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
        Object obj = original;
        List<Integer> li = (List<Integer>)obj;
        System.out.println(li); //[1, 2, 3] 
        Integer ei = new Integer(String.valueOf(li.get(0))); //java.lang.ClassCastException
```

Please see also [how-to-cast-an-object-to-an-int](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3661441/11266491)